# C Pointers with Strcat

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm trying to strcat char *. However, I've noticed an issue.

```
struct d{
    struct d* up   //parent
    char *path     //path to d
    char *name     //path + breadth = name
}

for(j=0; j<b;j++){
    struct d* breadth_p;
    breadth_p=malloc(sizeof(struct d));
    char buffer[256];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/%d", j)   //prepares buffer to have "/j"
    breadth_p->up=cur_parent;
    breath_path->path=cur_parent->up->name;
    breadth_name=strcat(breadth->path, buffer);
    printf("name: %s\n", breadth_p->name);
    free(breadth_p);
}
```

so say I pass the cur_parent name and path as root and b as 3. the following prints out

```
root/0
root/0/1
root/0/1/2
```

I'm assuming that I didn't free the breadth_p correctly so it's concatenating the previous names.

the results I'm expecting is

```
root/0
root/1
root/2
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: `strcat` appends to the first argument.

Comment: `strcat()` concatenates **and modifies in-place** its first argument to the second, and just returns the modified input buffer. [Docs here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcat.html)

Comment: You're never updating `cur_parent` or any other variable to point to a different node in your data structure, at least that I can see. So the result is that the successive `/<n>` strings are just getting appended one after the other to the same node.

Comment: I update cur_parent outside of the loop, but I excluded that from the code to do some isolated testing to make sure the inner portion is working. I'm wondering if free(breadth_p) will "free" the pointer, making it's previous data inaccessible to do the loop. I figured that I'm not doing that since it's appending the buffer onto the last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat()` **modifies** in-place **its first argument** (appends the second argument to it) and then simply returns the modified input buffer. [Read more about this behavior here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcat.html)

Comment: so in my code, is strcat appending the name to breadth_p path and thus permanently changing it?

Comment: @user1709294 Yes ... what else could it do? Where do you think the memory to store the catted text comes from? Note that you're copying text into whatever breadth_p->path and breadth_p->name point to, but you haven't set them to point anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you're expecting, use `strcpy()` and its brother `strncpy()` instead. Google for its usage.

Comment: Never ever recommend strncpy. If you don't know why, just search SO.